# combine two array using common field in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to combine two array by using key field.

```
$array1 = array( val1 => 'abc', val2 => '5' );
$array1 = array( val1 => 'bcd', val2 => '2' );

$array2 = array( val1 => 'abc', val3 => '1' );
$array2 = array( val1 => 'zzz', val3 => '3' );


array1:
val1    val2
abc       5 
bcd       2   

array2:
val1    val3
abc       1
zzz       3
```

The result have to be as follows;(requirement)

```
val1          val2             val3
abc             5                1
bcd             2                0
zzz             0                3
```

still now, i developed which further needs some modification to achieve the above table.

```
foreach($array1 as $ar1){
    $val1='';
    $val2='';
    $val3='';
    foreach($array2 as $ar2){
        if($ar1['val1']==$ar2['val1']){
           $val1=$ar1['val1'];
           $val2=$ar1['val2'];
           $val3=$ar2['val3'];
        }
    }

    $result=array(
        val1 => $val1,
        val2 => $val2,
        val3 => $val3
    );

}
```

This captures only common data.

Comment: The 4 arrays above (two redeclared) contains a syntax error, which is an extra comma before the last parenthesis. Also, replace the `=` with `==` when expressing conditions, else it won't work as expected.

Comment: @briosheje That is not a syntax error. In PHP, this is valid.

Comment: Another issue is that the keys in the array need to be strings ...

Comment: @medowlock: it depends on which php version you are using. in php5 it doesn't, but it will still notice something like `Use of undefined constant val1`, while in older versions of php it might even throw either syntax error or warning.

Comment: dont bother about syntax.  need logic guys. thanks.

Comment: @briosheje Not true, this is valid syntax in any PHP5 version (I believe also in PHP4 but not sure). The `use of undefined constant val1` appears because he does not have quotes (single or double) around the array keys.

Comment: @briosheje ...yes, commah and equal to equal to is syntax error.  please let us know the logic.

Comment: @medowlock: I said above that in php5 it doesn't, but in lower version of php it does, and it is actually a clever idea to correct these issues to prevent further problems. Moreover, i know that he needs either the single quotes or double quotes, it was just to point out that **the code might not want as expected whatsoever, so it is better to fix these issues NOW.** Besides, The question is unclear, because the array is redeclared TWICE. What are the arrays we should take? It is senseless.

Comment: Stop talking about syntax guys, he just wants the code, he doesn't need to the syntax to be correct to get the code to work..... To be honest, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: if you dont want to bother about proper syntax why should we bother to answer your question. also you have 4 arrays where 2 are redeclared which makes no sense at all

Comment: Wow, those code indentations really made this question answerable now....¬¬

Comment: Why are you assigning to the original array variables twice? Did you intend for these to be multidimensional arrays that you're pushing the arrays onto?

Comment: hello everyone, please check the updated post..it will show you exact requirement.  and syntax are correct.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = array();

// Make $result an associative array, containing contents of $array1
foreach ($array1 as $e) {
    $e['val3'] = 0; // val3 defaults to 0
    $result[$e['val1']] = $e;
}

// Now merge in $array2
foreach ($array2 as $e) {
    if (isset($result[$e['val1']])) {
        $result[$e['val1']]['val3'] = $e['val3'];
    } else {
        $e['val2'] = 0; // val2 defaults to 0
        $result[$e['val1']] = $e;
    }
}

// Convert to indexed array
$result = array_values($result);
```

BTW, the correct way to create the input arrays is:

```
$array1 = array(array( 'val1' => 'abc', 'val2' => '5' ),
                array( 'val1' => 'bcd', 'val2' => '2' )
);

$array2 = array(array( 'val1' => 'abc', 'val3' => '1' ),
                array( 'val1' => 'zzz', 'val3' => '3' )
);
```

Comment: isn't it a better way doing it like this: `$array1 = array("abc" => 5, "bcd" => 2);`, because in the question it's not a multidimensional array

Comment: @MaartenPeels yea the `The result have to be as follows` can be interpreted in many ways, OP should post a `print_r` desired output. i was going to comment it, but answer was accepted so no harm done

Comment: Look at the `array1:` and `array2:` tables in the question, it looks like a multidimensional array to me.

Comment: @MaartenPeels I suspect he actually meant to write `$array1[] = ...`.

Comment: Doesn't matter anymore tho, but below the 2(4) arrays, below this line: "I need to combine two array by using key field.". There are 2 arrays that aren't multidimensional, so i think it's the array notation that's wrong in this question.

Comment: It's clear from the example that `val1` is the key field. But he didn't implement the top-level array as an associative array. That's why my first step is to convert to associative.